# problems with using plotly in a shiny project

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am trying to start using plotly with shiny, but unfortunately it doesn't work with my code. As an example I wrote this (sorry that descriptions in UI part are in russian):

UI:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(mvtnorm)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Грачев Влад инкорпорейшн"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput('n_obs', 'Количество испытаний', min = 0, max = 1000, value = 500, animate = TRUE),
      sliderInput('prc', 'Средний рост детей', min = 170, max = 180, value = 175, step = 0.5, animate = TRUE),
      sliderInput('prp', 'Средний рост родителей', min = 170, max = 180, value = 175, step = 0.5, animate = TRUE),
      sliderInput('corr', 'Корреляция между ростом ребенка и ростом родителей', min = -1, max = 1, value = 0.5, step = 0.1, animate = TRUE),
      sliderInput('stdc', 'Стандартное отклонение роста детей', min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.5, animate = TRUE),
      sliderInput('stdp', 'Стандартное отклонение роста родителей', min = 0, max = 1, value = 0.5, animate = TRUE)

    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput('dotplot'), 
      plotOutput('plotl')
    )
  )
))
```

Server:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){
  update_x <- reactive({
    mu <- c(input$prc,input$prp)
    A <-matrix(
      c(input$stdc, input$corr*sqrt(input$stdc*input$stdp), input$corr*sqrt(input$stdc*input$stdp), input$stdp),
      nrow = 2
    )
    X <- rmvnorm(input$n_obs, mean = mu, sigma = A)
    X
  })

  output$dotplot <- renderPlot({
    X <- data.frame(update_x())
    g <- ggplot(X, aes(x=X[,1], y = X[,2]))  + geom_jitter() + stat_smooth()
    gg <- ggplotly(g)
    gg
  })
  output$plotl <- renderPlotly({
    X <- data.frame(update_x())
    g <-ggplot(X, aes(X[,2])) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.2) 
    gg <- ggplotly(g)
    gg
  })
})
```

It works without plotly (just ordinary renderPlot and ggplot graph):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58LHB.png)

But when i am starting the code above it doesn't show any graphs or warnings (only empty space) and there are 2 warnings in the console: Using size for a discrete variable is not advised.

Thanks in advance
Vlad

Comment: in ui.R replace plotOutput('plotl') by plotlyOutput('plotl')

Comment: @MLavoie Thank you so much!